# How move a row to a second sheet if the column isn't blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add a script that moves a row to another tab if a column isn"t Blank

Here is the script i am using. The "NOT BLANK" is the part i need to figure out. i understand how to move it if it has a specific value but want to know how to get it to move if it has ANY text.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Current" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "NOT BLANK") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Complete");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);   
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```

if the targeted column isn't blank to move the row to a second tab

Comment: i"m pretty new to any sort of scripting. I can't get the format to work script works when i put the value but want it to move if I add any text to the cell

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the `edit` link under your question to add code, don't place it in the comments. I've updated your question for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if(s.getName() == "Current" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "NOT BLANK")
```

To this:

```
if(event.range.getSheet().getName()=="Current" && event.range.columnStart==1 && event.value.length>0)
```

This is what I came up with after playing with it a bit.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=e.source;
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var col=rg.columnStart;
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet46" && col==1 && e.value.length>0) {
    var row=rg.rowStart;
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet50");
    var target=targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);   
    sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); 
    sh.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```